# Server returns HTML instead of expected JSON response

Tags: html, json, jsp, server

The server is returning html code with JavaScript instead of returning a straight JSON response to my android application. 
I have set the POST header Content-type as JSON, following is the code for parsing

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url,List params ) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json");

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

But the Log.e("JSON",json) is printing the following :-

```
E/JSON: <html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("61752b71ddbf41dbe3e72a15586b68db");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://recipebook.epizy.com/RecipeBook/?i=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

So it's obviously unable to convert that into a JSONObject. 
The JavaScript option on my default browser is enabled. 
Because of the object being null, I'm facing NullPointerExceptions as well. 
But they will probably vanish once I get the proper JSON response. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This looks like you are using some kind of framework, and that is likely set to return any content within a default HTML page template, unless instructed otherwise. So go check the documentation on how to prevent that.

Comment: [W3 JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Check out your URL, it may be wrong. If the server is returning true HTML, it may not be a bug but simply a wrong call.